# android imageview long press and regular press

Tags: android, imageview, contextmenu

I have an imageview where I need to have both long presses (for a context menu) and regular presses working. I can get one or the other working, but not both. What did I miss? The code below only works for regular presses. As soon as I touch the screen, it starts executing the onTouch code.

```
 ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.visible_image);
 image.setLongClickable(true);
 image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // disable the screen taps for 500ms
            DecodeActionDownEvent(v, ev, bm2);
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
     }
        return true;
    }
 });
 registerForContextMenu(image);
```

...

```
 @Override
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
     ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Edit");
    ArrayList<String> menuItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    menuItems.add("Edit page settings");
    menuItems.add("Edit page objects");
    menuItems.add("Edit this object");
    for (int i = 0; i<menuItems.size(); i++) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems.get(i));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try to do it this way:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    //your stuff
        return true;
    }
});
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClick(View v) {
        //your stuff
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: OK, I had not tried that, and it looks like it will work. Can you tell me how to get the click/long click x&y coordinates from the View v that is passed in?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I still need to keep around the OnTouch listener. Thanks :)

Comment: The `return true` is the important bit for anyone who already had both listeners but had used the default auto-complete for `onLongClick`

Answer (score 3):

After much looking and experimenting this is the best solution I have found to achieve this type of behavior:

```
//Define these variables at the beginning of your Activity or Fragment:
private long then;
private int longClickDuration = 5000; //for long click to trigger after 5 seconds

...

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.visible_image);
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
          then = (long) System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
          if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - then) > longClickDuration) {
            /* Implement long click behavior here */
            System.out.println("Long Click has happened!");
            return false;
          } else {
            /* Implement short click behavior here or do nothing */
            System.out.println("Short Click has happened...");
            return true;
          }
        }
        return true;
      }
    });
```

Comment: I think a click has an additional condition: the finger should not have moved too much (like with a swipe). So keeping thenX and thenY too might be a good idea here ...

Answer (score 2):

To get x and y coordinates, set a touch listener

```
      ImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
      {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
           //And u can get x and y values like:

           x = event.getX(); 
           y = event.getY() ;
        }
      }
```